# How do I maintain the user Wish List in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented the functionality of Wish List. If the user clicks on the add in the Wish List, the products are added in the user's Wish List, but the problem is that the particular user's Wish List items are also added in another logged-in user's Wish List. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far and then ask your question with reference to your code ?

Comment: Can you please post your scenario with code snippet here?

Comment: sir,i will post my code,so check that.

Comment: you should add it to your question (use edit), not as an answer...